# How can I distinguish short from long button press in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, stm32

I wrote a code for determining the push button state wheather it's long pressed or not. By the way this function is called by a timer interrupt routine in every 1 ms.

If you pressed more than 1 second, LongPressed is active ShortPressed is passive .so vice versa.

**1-** But it seems really dummy how can I make it shorter and more efficient according to both readibilty and professional rules?

BTW I updated the code like below.

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{   
    /*button pressed and count*/
    if(!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13))
    {
        usTick++;
    }
    /*not pressed*/
    else
    {
        if( usTick > 1000){
            ButtonState.PressedState = LongPressed;
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);       
            usTick = 0;
        }
        else if( usTick >350){
            ButtonState.PressedState = ShortPressed;
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);               
            usTick = 0;
        }               
        usTick = 0;
    }
}
```

**2-** What should I add or change to get double Tap pressing information in this updated code?

Comment: Might want to move this over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Might be better to rely on `GPIO_PIN_13` interrupts rather than timer interrupts.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. I'll move it

Comment: BTW, what's the point of maintaining both `ShortPressed` and `ShortPressed`? Just maintain a single enumerator indicating 3 states (off, short and long).

Comment: I might be reading the code incorrectly, but doesn't your first `if` determine if the button is still pressed? If so, why the need to do yet another `if( ButtonState.Released == FALSE)` in the `else`? In the else can't you just assume the button is released and just check how long is was pressed?

Comment: Your updated code looks more reasonable now. Only thing is you say the timer is firing every 1ms but your tick counter is named usTick. Maybe that should be msTick?

Comment: For double-tap detection you'll need to compare the tick difference between two button closed states. You'll need a `lastClosedTickCount` variable that is perhaps `static` to the interrupt routine so the value is saved between calls. And compare it against `usTick`. If you detect a double-tap then set set both `usTick` and `lastClosedTickCount` to 0 to prepare for detecting next double-tap.

Comment: Why not just subtract button down time from button up time and compare to 1000.  Are you doing anything before the button is released?

Comment: @stark Because the code is zeroing `usTick` when the button is released the code is basically subtracting button down time from button up time.

Comment: Where are you de-bouncing the button?

Comment: I agree with barak manos, if possible I also would use the EXTI Interrupt of GPIO_PIN_13. In the ISR you can qery the pin state and save the systick time. Then you can just determine the difference.

Comment: But I also agree with  Chimera, debouncing is also something you should take into account.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every STM32 timer has "external trigger synchronization" function. You can read about it in timer functional description in reference manual. You can use "Slave mode: Trigger mode" to start counting on "button down" event. And in EXTI interrupt of "button up event" you can read timer counter and do your business.

I don't know how to implement this via HAL, but Standard Peripheral Library should have the example.

Comment: Also STM32 timers have PWM input mode that can be used to measure duration of a single signal. This way is more difficult in coding, but also more beautiful. Maybe there is other ways, cause STM32 timers are very very clever, to find them you can read reference manual table of contents at least:)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Your code is only able to handle 1 button. Make it object oriented to read ***n*** buttons.

1 ms is much too fast. 20 ms should work fine. Remember: humans are slow.

**2)** I once had spent some time creating a LED controller with two pushbutton rotary encoders. These would feature advanced programming methods by means of pushing them long or multiple times. You could use the result of my sparring (it was never completed) as inspiration. The button code is fairly complex, it should fulfill your needs. And I remember it to be functional.

https://github.com/Jeroen6/LED-Rotary-Dimmer-SW/blob/master/user/button.c
https://github.com/Jeroen6/LED-Rotary-Dimmer-SW/blob/master/user/button.h

*Forgive me for not having the indentations worked out correctly.*